# How to Globally Use wp_localize_script() Ajax URL

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have added this to my `functions.php` and need to use `ajaxURL` in all of enqueued scripts in the template (instead of enqueuing only one script here

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajaxify_enqueue_scripts' );
function ajaxify_enqueue_scripts() {
   wp_localize_script( 'ajaxify', 'ajaxURL', array('ajax_url' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/app/login.php' ));
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_set_ajaxify', 'set_ajaxify' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_set_ajaxify', 'set_ajaxify' );
```

but when I try to call an ajax method I am getting this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxURL is not defined
```

Is there any way to add  the `ajaxURL` to all scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajaxify_enqueue_scripts' );

function ajaxify_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('ajaxify', get_template_directory_uri() . '/test.js');
    wp_localize_script( 'ajaxify', 'ajaxURL', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put This Code :

```
function your_function_name() {

  wp_register_script('ajaxify', get_template_directory_uri() . '/your-jsname.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
  wp_enqueue_script('ajaxify');

  wp_localize_script('ajaxify', 'ajaxURL', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),'siteurl' => site_url() ) );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_function_name' );
```